# How to enforce particular order in UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

What I'm after:

```
--heading--
xxx 111
xxx 222
xxx 333
yyy 111
yyy 222
yyy 333
```

The heading is a constant value and it needs to stay at the top. The numbers (111, 222, 333) are values selected from a table. The letters (xxx, yyy) are constant values. What I need is to have 3 'x' rows in a row, and then 3 'y' rows in a row. When I use UNION ALL I'm getting:

```
--heading--
xxx 111
yyy 111
xxx 222
yyy 222
xxx 333
yyy 333
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT '--heading--' + 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'xxx ' + Column1
FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'yyy ' + Column1
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY` ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a weight column and sort by it:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS SortOrder, '--heading--' AS Column1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'xxx ' + Column1
    FROM T_UnitTypes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'yyy ' + Column1
    FROM T_UnitTypes
) AS x
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Use like this -

```
SELECT 0 Ord, '--heading--' Datas
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 ord, CONCAT(a.t, yourcolName) z FROM Table1
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 'xxx' ) ) as  a(t) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ord, CONCAT(b.t, yourcolName) z  FROM Table1
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 'yyy' ) ) as  b(t) 
)u ORDER BY ord
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with one scan of your table. Do not know will it be faster

```
select
    val
from (
    select
        q.rn, val = q.val + t.Column1
    from
        Table1 t
        cross apply (values ('xxx', 1),('yyy', 2)) q(val, rn)
    union all
    select 0, '--heading--'
) t
order by rn
```